# One-time scheduled task that fires on logon for another local user in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a one-time scheduled task that fires on login for a local user that is not the user creating the scheduled task.  What is the Powershell to do this?  I'm using Powershell v3 on Win Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1.  I need the task to run a line of powershell.

Comment: Do you know the other user, or do you want any user other than the current user?

Comment: I know the other user.  I have a PSCredential object for that user.

Comment: In fact, the context is that I've created the user and I plan to restart the machine and auto-login as that user.  So at this point, the user has never logged-into the machine.

Comment: So if you're going to immediately reboot and login as that use just put it in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Comment: any consequence if the ComputerName is changed before the reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer so this can be resolved.

If you're going to immediately reboot and login as that user just put it in :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Then the next user to login (any user) will initiate the command.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule it to run from this registry key.   The gotcha is you'll need to do it through the HKEY_USERS\SID instead of CurrentUser.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

HKEY_USERS\S-1-6236236236124362346346-BIG-LONG-NUMBER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Here is how to get the users SID.

```
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("KNUCKLE-DRAGGER")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$strSID = $strSID.Value
$strSID
```

Then drop that $strSID variable inside the HKEY_USERS path to automate creating the command in the correct location.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "registry::HKEY_USERS\$strSID\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" -Name "MyBatch" -Value "C:\SomeScript.cmd"
```

Comment: HKU doesn't work for me because the key doesn't exist yet.  I am attempting to access this key right after creating a new user.  Because that user has not logged-on yet, I think the key is not available?

Comment: yeah I know, not a big deal.  Still gonna leave the answer for future readers.  but for next time put those important details in your question, as it will change the answers we give you.

Comment: Agreed!  Sorry for leaving those details out.  In general I like the HKU approach because it guarantees the script is only ever run for that particular user.